# Permalink for regular posts "/blog/"

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, blog-page

I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish the following:

`http://www.mydomain/blog/my-blog-post/`

I'm using the `/%postname%/` for my permalink structure, but this eliminates the "/blog/" from all posts that are technically blog only.

Is there a way to ensure that "/blog/" is within the URL structure for regular Posts?

---

In addition, is there a way to REMOVE the post type slug from the URL for a Custom Post Type?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've come to accept that this is just not possible with WordPress. You MUST have a slug for a custom post type.

Answer (score 1):

For sure. Just set your structure to: /blog/%postname%/ or /blog/%category%/%postname%/. Permalink structure is only for posts ;D

Comment: One thing though ... what about Custom Post Types? I don't want `/blog/` to be apart of their URLs...

Comment: But /blog/ will show only in posts.This is not what you need?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify ... I want "/blog/" to be apart of the URL for the generic "post" type ... however, for custom post types, I do NOT want "/blog/" to be a part of the URL. So the only time "/blog/" shows up in the URL is when browsing the generic "post" type.